# Text transparency over opacity CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

Good day! I would like to ask on how can I achieve this kind of layout?
As you can see there was a background then another container with opacity 
Then the text is transparent.

[image]

I tried to work on it but I failed, here my current work. I used to clip the text to the background, its something it looks like but the approach is wrong.

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="landing-sec">
     <div class="container-fluid sec_about" >
         <h1>stack overflow</h1>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here's my current sass:

```
.sec_about
{
  margin-top: 80px;
  background-color:white;
  height:450px;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  h1
  {
    background: url('../img/bg1.jpg') no-repeat;

   // text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: $roboto_bold;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: 30px;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }

}
```

Thank you for your help. I'll appreciate it gladly and it will serve to me as a lesson.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `background-clip` for this. Check this **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbwLXw)**

Or have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.sec_about {
  position: relative;
}

.clip-text {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/480/200/abstract/7);
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.clip-text:before,
.clip-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.clip-text:before {
  z-index: -2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: inherit;
}

.clip-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: .125em;
  right: .125em;
  bottom: .125em;
  left: .125em;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="landing-sec">
     <div class="container-fluid sec_about" >
         <div class="clip-text">stack overflow</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yah I used backgroud-clip. Nice, but I not working on me. Can you help me out ? thanks

Comment: @Jonas I've updated my code with your given code, please have a look and let me know if it helps?